# Apache rewrite rule for a folder to a different domain

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, subdomain, directory, path

I need to redirect all requests concerning a folder to another (old) web server called www2 keeping the entire original path, for example

https://www.example.org/thisfolder/maps/map.jsp?id=2345
must be redirected to
https://www2.example.org/thisfolder/maps/map.jsp?id=2345

I think the solution is to use the mod_rewrite module with RewriteRule directive and should be quite simple, but I cannot find a working example. I tried with

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    LoadModule rewrite_module  modules/mod_rewrite.so
</IfModule>
<Directory "/thisfolder">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase "/thisfolder"
    RewriteRule "(.*)" "https://www2.example.org/$1"
</Directory>
```

This is an Apache2.4 installation running on Linux CentOS 7.6 (Red Hat Enterprise).
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** that such a simple redirect requirement is a [text book case](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) where you don't need mod_rewrite.

> mod_rewrite should be considered a last resort, when other alternatives are found wanting. Using it when there are simpler alternatives leads to configurations which are confusing, fragile, and hard to maintain.

A simple
[`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)
directive will already be sufficient in your case:

```
 Redirect "/thisfolder" "https://www2.example.org/thisfolder"
```

Comment: Thank you HBruijn. So easy :)

Comment: Indeed, not complicated at all. - Once you know where in the extensive documentation for Apache httpd you need to look though ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `<Directory>` directive works for filesystem paths, not URL paths, so we need to change it to `<Location>` and also we have to capture properly the the request after `"thisfolder/"`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule "^/thisfolder/(.*)" "https://www2.example.org/thisfolder/$1" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```